# FAT32 vs. NTFS microSD card

Tags: memory, ntfs

***UPDATE***: OK, so in response to the suggestions below, I formatted to exFAT. Transferred a movie on to it. Put it in the tablet. Guess what? It won't read it. Says the card is blank and needs to be formatted. So I guess the tablet won't read exFAT-formatted cards. Any other suggestions? 
By the way, this is the tablet I'm working with: [phonearena.com/phones/Verizon-Wireless-Ellipsis-7_id8207](http://OK,%20so%20I%20formatted%20to%20exFAT.%20Transferred%20a%20movie%20on%20to%20it.%20Put%20it%20in%20the%20tablet.%20Guess%20what?%20It%20won't%20read%20it.%20Says%20the%20card%20is%20blank%20and%20needs%20to%20be%20formatted.%20So%20I%20guess%20the%20tablet%20won't%20read%20exFAT-formatted%20cards.%20Any%20other%20suggestions?%20By%20the%20way,%20this%20is%20the%20tablet%20I'm%20working%20with:%20phonearena.com/phones/Verizon-Wireless-Ellipsis-7_id8207%20Like%20I%20said,%20it's%20very%20basic.) 
Like I said, it's very basic.

First off, please don't tell me to reformat my drive to NTFS. LOL

I have a very basic tablet that will hold an external microSD card up to 32GB. Obviously, in today’s world, that doesn’t mean much. I bought a 256GB microSD to put in there but found it won’t work unless it’s formatted to FAT32. OK, done. However, as you know, you can’t transfer anything to it over 4GB – a problem if I want to transfer movies and the like! I tried reformatting to NTFS, but then of course the tablet wouldn’t read the card.

Is there a workaround to this so I can transfer large files onto the card – and still have my tablet be able to read them? The tablet itself only has 8GB of storage on it, most of which is filled by the o/s and apps already; there’s less than 1GB free. I'd really like to be able to travel with my tablet and watch movies, but I'm kinda stuck.

The above is about the extent of my knowledge with this stuff. If there IS a workaround, could you please “dumb it down” for me so I can easily do it? ;)

Help?

Thanx,
Jamie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android tablets only support FAT and FAT32 out of the box. There's also a chance that some ext* filesystem would work, but Windows doesn't support these.

Some Android devices can be flashed with modified firmware that supports NTFS, exFAT and more, but flashing such firmware requires advanced knowledge about Android devices and invalidates your warranty (with rare exceptions). It also involves risk of making the device unusable.

All in all, you're out of luck if you want to store files larger than 4 GB

However, maybe you don't need epic-quality FullHD movies on your tablet? It has just a 1280x800px screen anyway, so 1280x720 should be good enough. You can get really good quality under 4 gigs with this resolution. You can compress your movies to be under 4 GB on your PC, then copy them to standard FAT32-formatted SD card.

Comment: Oh, I don't care about them being epic quality. As long as their watchable and not so pixelated you can't see what's going on, I'm totally fine with that. In addition to movies, I have Tivo files that I'm converting to MP4s, and they average about 6 or 7GB. So given that info, how do I compress them, as you suggest? And if I compress, will I be able to view them on the tabloid?

Comment: @jamie, re-encoding to 1280x720 resolution with 5 Mb/s constant bitrate will result in good quality video sized about 2.25 GB per hour. Lowering bitrate makes files smaller at the cost of quality. You can estimate resulting file sizes by multiplying bitrate in Mb/s by 0.45 and then by length in hours. Eg. 1 hr 30 mins with 5 Mb/s bitrate: `5 * 0.45 * 1.5 = 3.375 GB`. I think [Handbrake](https://handbrake.fr/) should let you do that reencoding.

Comment: Thank you! So I downloaded Handbrake. I don't know how to upload a screenshot here, but where in the program would I find the re-encoding option? I selected my source file, looks like it defaults to mp4, but where do I make it 1280x720 and change the constant bitrate? Sorry, totally new at this. Help is much appreciated.

Comment: @jamie Select source file, then *Android Tablet* profile from the right pane. On the *Video* tab change *Framerate* to *Same as source*, select *Constant framerate*. Select *Avg bitrate* and enter expected bitrate value there (5 Mbps = 5000 kbps). Enter *Destination* path and click *Start*.

Comment: Well, that sorta worked! It definitely shrank the file (now <1MB - it's 151,791KB) so it went onto the FAT32 card. The sound is fine but you can't see the picture. It's like it's just shadows, with ginormous pixels. I used your specs, above, so I'm not sure what else to do. Is there another setting or number that I can use that will help with the image? Guessing if I make it a little bigger somehow (just not sure what to change?), the picture will be better? I obviously have room if it went from 6.6GB to a few hundred KB. Sorry to keep bugging you but you've been so helpful. Thanx!

Comment: Also, I just realized something. By doing your formula above (bitratex0.45x1.5hours), that comes out to 3.37, which I'm guessing is 3.37GB in size? Something is weird, then. The aforementioned file (see above post) is 2 hours, so according to the formula, it'd be 4.5. A, that's a problem with the 4GB FAT32 transfer restriction and B, like I said, my file is not even 1MB, much less 4.5GB (weird?). Either I'm totally missing something or I did something very wrong. I put in all of the specs you gave me. Guessing it's so pixelated because the file is so small, but... help?

Comment: @jamie Bitrate tells encoder how much disk space it can use for every frame. 5 Mbps is just an example, it would in fact result in approx. 4.5 GB file, so you need to use lower bitrate. 4 Mbps will give you ~3.6 GB file (plus some overhead for audio). The video anomaly you've described could occur with *very* low bitrate. Notice that Handbrake expects bitrate in *kbps*, not *Mbps*, so you have to multiply by 1000 (4 Mbps = 1000 kbps).

Comment: So now I feel like an idiot! LOL No _wonder_ the file size was so small! ;) OK, I'll redo it with the right multipliers and see what happens. Thanx for the clarification. Fingers crossed it all works this time!

Comment: You. Are. My. Hero!!! How do I give you kudos on this site? Thank you, thank you, thank you! It worked _perfectly_ and the resolution is just fine, especially on this low-grade tablet.

Comment: Just one more question. I have a folder full of mp4s that need to be converted. Do I have to do them one at a time? I see there's a "select folder" option for the source, and it scans all of the files in said folder, but when the first one finishes, it doesn't seem to go on to the next one for conversion in the folder (and I'm not sure how it chooses the one to convert). Is there some setting that will allow it to finish one and go on to the next one in the folder?

Comment: @jamie I'm glad that it worked. You can [mark my answer as accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/267029) by clicking the check mark next to it, we'll both get few reputation points. Here's how to convert multiple files at once: click *Tools* menu > *Options* and then *Output Files* in the left pane. Make sure that *Automatically name output files* is enabled and change *Default Path* to some folder. Then click *Close* at the bottom. Before clicking *Start* click the little arrow next to *Add To Queue* and click *Add All*, then *Start*.

Comment: CHECKED!! I have a single file about halfway through the transfer process, but I will try your multi-file suggestion when it's finished. I am so happy to have found this site and that you answered! I was contemplating having to buy a new tablet with more space but you just saved me from having to do that.

Comment: I must be missing a step. I made the modification in _Tools_ that you suggested, putting in a path to a folder where I want my shrunken files to land, and closed the window. I hit _Source_ to choose my source file and selected the folder. But when I hit _Add to Queue_ and selected all, it only put in two files and gave me this error message when I hit start: _There are jobs on the queue with the same destination path. Please choose a different path for this job._ What am I doing wrong? Is there a way to put a screenshot in here so you can see my settings?

Comment: @jamie Frankly, I don't know how to solve this. You can [ask a new question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask) and explain what you're trying to do and how it fails. There's also an option to include screenshots in a question, but you may be unable to do it due to your low reputation. In that case, create an album on imgur.com and post a link. Somebody with more rep will include them properly for you.

Comment: OK, I may do that. Or I may just do them individually and let them run while I do other things, unless that becomes ridiculous. Either way, thank you again for all of your help!

Comment: would you mind taking a look at this thread, giving me your thoughts? I've been able to get the file size down enough, all using the bitrate of 4, like we discussed. Some are able to transfer, some are not. (http://superuser.com/questions/1036468/can-play-mp4-on-laptop-but-not-on-microusb/1036537?noredirect=1#comment1448827_1036537) Specifically, check out the exchange with @taltamir. Thank you!

Comment: Also, how did you get the hyperlink on regular text, like in your comment starting, "Frankly, I don't know how to solve this. You can _ask a new question_ and explain..." where the _ask a new question_ is the hyperlink. How did you do that?

Comment: @jamie [Markdown formatting](https://superuser.com/help/formatting).

Comment: For some reason, I can't tag you in my responses on the other post. I'm really sorry to bug you again, but I did put up some more information, both in the comments and in the original question (there's an update with new MediaInfo data). Would you mind taking a look and giving me your thoughts when you have a chance? Thanx so much.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the tablet you're using, it might be able to read exFAT. This is an extended version of the FAT-filesystem, that allows single files >4 GB. Simply try to format the card from your pc, then plug it in the tablet and see if it is readable.

Comment: Note: exFAT is really only tangentially related to FAT. Its main relationship is that it was designed for the same use cases that FAT used to be used but can't anymore because of its constraints. But more importantly: exFAT is a proprietary filesystem guarded by patents and governed by strict licensing terms. Thus, it is not supported by some operating systems and devices.

Answer (score 0):

Well under Linux this would be pretty easy, for Windows you just need a tool like [GSplit](http://www.gdgsoft.com/gsplit/) to split the file and transfer it (assuming you run Windows on both the tablet and your PC)

Answer (score 0):

Ok. The best solution for it is to change your SD card from FAT32 to exFAT filesystem. To do this you should backup all your data from your SDCard.

After that you must format your card into exFAT

**If you're using linux:**

1. Open terminal and type the following command in order to install exFAT formatting utility:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install exfat-utils
   ```
2. Then, in the same terminal list your device list using this command:

   ```
   lsblk
   ```

It will show you the disk list, find your SDCard name, it's called sdX# very often (where # means a number). Something like this:

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 596.2G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   450M  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    0   100M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda3   8:3    0    16M  0 part 
├─sda4   8:4    0   500G  0 part 
└─sda6   8:6    0  95.6G  0 part /
sdX      9:0    0    16G  0 disk
└─sdX1   9:1    0    16G  0 part /
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

3. Run this command (adjust it to your case):

   ```
   mkfs.exfat /dev/sdX1
   ```
4. Confirm any warning or message it shows, and done.

**If you're using windows**

1. Open Computer in Default File Explorer.
2. Right click to your external SD Card and click on 'Format'.
3. Select filesystem as 'exFAT'.
4. Choose a label or something else you want.
5. Choose if it's a Quick Format or not (Uncheck this option if you want it quick).
6. Click on Format and wait some time.
7. Done!

**After formatting (Linux/Windows):**

1. Safely remove your SDCard and plug it in again.
2. Restore all your data to SDCard and then put it back into your tablet.
3. Done, enjoy your movies!

**NOTE:** It is important to guess if your tablet supports exFAT filesystem, mostly they do.

**GOOD LUCK!**

Comment: OK, so I formatted to exFAT. Transferred a movie on to it. Put it in the tablet. Guess what? It won't read it. Says the card is blank and needs to be formatted. So I guess the tablet won't read exFAT-formatted cards.

Any other suggestions? By the way, this is the tablet I'm working with: http://www.phonearena.com/phones/Verizon-Wireless-Ellipsis-7_id8207

Like I said, it's very basic.