# Can play mp4 on laptop but not on microUSB

Tags: file-transfer

***UPDATE:*** *I have put two files below that have been compressed and both play on my computer. The one marked **EWL - Hannah** can be copied onto the microUSB and played with no issues. The one marked **Deadly Adoption** seems to be corrupted during transfer (The info for both of these was taken from the files on my hard drive, not the microUSB.). I don't know what I'm looking at in this info, but I'm hoping one of you might. Can you see something different between the two that might be causing the corruption? (Sorry, the spacing is wonky, but someone fixed it last time; I don't know how, otherwise I'd do it myself here.)*

I have several mp4 files that I want to put on my microUSB card so I can watch them on my tablet. When they're housed on my computer, all of them play just fine. However, when I move them over to my microUSB, neither the computer will play them nor the tablet. The rub? *SOME* of them will play on the microUSB, some of them wont -- but *ALL* of them will play on the computer. Am I missing something here?

This is a **WORKING** file:

```
  General
Complete name                            : C:\Users\Jamie\Desktop\VIDEOS\Converted\EWL - Hannah.mp4
Format                                   : MPEG-4
Format profile                           : Base Media / Version 2
Codec ID                                 : mp42 (isom/iso2/avc1/mp41)
File size                                : 2.15 GiB
Duration                                 : 1h 0mn
Overall bit rate mode                    : Variable
Overall bit rate                         : 5 139 Kbps
Encoded date                             : UTC 2016-02-03 22:17:19
Tagged date                              : UTC 2016-02-03 22:17:19
Writing application                      : HandBrake 0.10.3 2016012200

Video
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : Main@L3.1
Format settings, CABAC                   : Yes
Format settings, ReFrames                : 4 frames
Codec ID                                 : avc1
Codec ID/Info                            : Advanced Video Coding
Duration                                 : 1h 0mn
Bit rate                                 : 5 000 Kbps
Width                                    : 1 280 pixels
Height                                   : 720 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 16:9
Frame rate mode                          : Constant
Frame rate                               : 24.000 fps
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.226
Stream size                              : 2.10 GiB (97%)
Writing library                          : x264 core 142 r2479 dd79a61
Encoding settings                        : cabac=1 / ref=3 / deblock=1:0:0 / analyse=0x1:0x111 / me=hex / subme=7 / psy=1 / psy_rd=1.00:0.00 / mixed_ref=1 / me_range=16 / chroma_me=1 / trellis=1 / 8x8dct=0 / cqm=0 / deadzone=21,11 / fast_pskip=1 / chroma_qp_offset=-2 / threads=6 / lookahead_threads=1 / sliced_threads=0 / nr=0 / decimate=1 / interlaced=0 / bluray_compat=0 / constrained_intra=0 / bframes=3 / b_pyramid=2 / b_adapt=1 / b_bias=0 / direct=1 / weightb=1 / open_gop=0 / weightp=2 / keyint=240 / keyint_min=24 / scenecut=40 / intra_refresh=0 / rc_lookahead=40 / rc=abr / mbtree=1 / bitrate=5000 / ratetol=1.0 / qcomp=0.60 / qpmin=0 / qpmax=69 / qpstep=4 / vbv_maxrate=14000 / vbv_bufsize=14000 / nal_hrd=none / filler=0 / ip_ratio=1.40 / aq=1:1.00
Encoded date                             : UTC 2016-02-03 22:17:19
Tagged date                              : UTC 2016-02-03 22:17:19
Color range                              : Limited
Color primaries                          : BT.709
Transfer characteristics                 : BT.709
Matrix coefficients                      : BT.709

Audio
ID                                       : 2
Format                                   : AAC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Audio Codec
Format profile                           : LC
Codec ID                                 : 40
Duration                                 : 1h 0mn
Bit rate mode                            : Variable
Bit rate                                 : 128 Kbps
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Channel positions                        : Front: L R
Sampling rate                            : 44.1 KHz
Frame rate                               : 43.066 fps (1024 spf)
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Stream size                              : 55.0 MiB (2%)
Title                                    : Stereo / Stereo
Language                                 : English
Default                                  : Yes
Alternate group                          : 1
Encoded date                             : UTC 2016-02-03 22:17:19
Tagged date                              : UTC 2016-02-03 22:17:19
```

This is from a **NON-WORKING** file.

```
General
Complete name                            : C:\Users\Jamie\Desktop\VIDEOS\Converted\Deadly Adoption.mp4
Format                                   : MPEG-4
Format profile                           : Base Media / Version 2
Codec ID                                 : mp42 (isom/iso2/avc1/mp41)
File size                                : 3.63 GiB
Duration                                 : 2h 5mn
Overall bit rate mode                    : Variable
Overall bit rate                         : 4 131 Kbps
Encoded date                             : UTC 2016-02-04 00:39:52
Tagged date                              : UTC 2016-02-04 00:39:52
Writing application                      : HandBrake 0.10.3 2016012200

Video
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : Main@L3.1
Format settings, CABAC                   : Yes
Format settings, ReFrames                : 4 frames
Codec ID                                 : avc1
Codec ID/Info                            : Advanced Video Coding
Duration                                 : 2h 5mn
Bit rate                                 : 4 000 Kbps
Width                                    : 1 280 pixels
Height                                   : 720 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 16:9
Frame rate mode                          : Constant
Frame rate                               : 24.000 fps
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.181
Stream size                              : 3.52 GiB (97%)
Writing library                          : x264 core 142 r2479 dd79a61
Encoding settings                        : cabac=1 / ref=3 / deblock=1:0:0 / analyse=0x1:0x111 / me=hex / subme=7 / psy=1 / psy_rd=1.00:0.00 / mixed_ref=1 / me_range=16 / chroma_me=1 / trellis=1 / 8x8dct=0 / cqm=0 / deadzone=21,11 / fast_pskip=1 / chroma_qp_offset=-2 / threads=6 / lookahead_threads=1 / sliced_threads=0 / nr=0 / decimate=1 / interlaced=0 / bluray_compat=0 / constrained_intra=0 / bframes=3 / b_pyramid=2 / b_adapt=1 / b_bias=0 / direct=1 / weightb=1 / open_gop=0 / weightp=2 / keyint=240 / keyint_min=24 / scenecut=40 / intra_refresh=0 / rc_lookahead=40 / rc=abr / mbtree=1 / bitrate=4000 / ratetol=1.0 / qcomp=0.60 / qpmin=0 / qpmax=69 / qpstep=4 / vbv_maxrate=14000 / vbv_bufsize=14000 / nal_hrd=none / filler=0 / ip_ratio=1.40 / aq=1:1.00
Encoded date                             : UTC 2016-02-04 00:39:52
Tagged date                              : UTC 2016-02-04 00:39:52
Color range                              : Limited
Color primaries                          : BT.709
Transfer characteristics                 : BT.709
Matrix coefficients                      : BT.709

Audio
ID                                       : 2
Format                                   : AAC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Audio Codec
Format profile                           : LC
Codec ID                                 : 40
Duration                                 : 2h 5mn
Bit rate mode                            : Variable
Bit rate                                 : 128 Kbps
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Channel positions                        : Front: L R
Sampling rate                            : 44.1 KHz
Frame rate                               : 43.066 fps (1024 spf)
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Stream size                              : 116 MiB (3%)
Title                                    : Stereo / Stereo
Language                                 : English
Default                                  : Yes
Alternate group                          : 1
Encoded date                             : UTC 2016-02-04 00:39:52
Tagged date                              : UTC 2016-02-04 00:39:52
```

Comment: Is there any correlation with file size or type. What happens when you re-copy the non-working files?

Comment: Please install [MediaInfo](https://mediaarea.net/pl/MediaInfo) (it comes with some bloatware, select *I do not accept* to prevent installing it). Then run it and open a **working** file. In the *View* menu choose *Text*, copy everything and add it to your question. Then do the same thing for a broken file. Make sure to state which one is which.

Comment: @gronostaj Done. There was virtually no info in the bad file. I don't know if that tells you what you were looking for, but... sorry the spacing is so wonky. I can try to do a screen shot but don't know how to attach it. Lemme know if you need that instead. Thanx.

Comment: Looks like the file is completely damaged. Is it the same when you check it with MediaInfo directly after conversion, before transferring to SD card?

Comment: Have you tried a different memory stick? It sounds suspiciously like this one is defective.

Comment: @gronostaj I have a folder on my laptop in which I have placed all of my HandBrake files; it's the path I have for HandBrake to deposit them, so they go directly there. All of the files in there are fine. It's not until I move them over to the card that they get damaged. Like I said before, some move over fine, others... not so much. I'm doing a drag/drop to copy them from file manager to the card; is there another/better method that may stop the corruption from happening? **SIDE NOTE:** I did try the file on a USB and it played just fine. Maybe there IS something wrong with the card?

Comment: Are you copying files through your tablet connected with a USB cable or through a card reader?

Comment: @gronostaj I've tried it both ways. I have two card readers -- one that goes in the SD slot on my laptop, one that looks like USB drive and the micro slides into it -- and both of them seem to have this issue. I tried putting the card into the tablet and connecting via USB cable, seems to be the same. So yeah, maybe the card is bad? Ugh.

Comment: Try with a different memory card as Mokubai suggested. I can't think of any reasonable explanation for this issue other than failing card.

Comment: @gronostaj I think you both may well be right. I was hoping that wasn't it, but I'm thinking it probably is. Stupid thing is brand new, too. Guess I'll be sending it back.

Answer (score 0):

So just to be clear... The files on the microUSB work on your computer but *not* your tablet? If so, than this leads me to imply that your tablet does not support the file type (mp4, mov, etc.), the video encoding (MPEG, H.264, etc.) or the audio encoding (mp3, aac, etc.). If this is the case, you will have to convert your video files to a format compatible with your tablet or tablet's video player.

Another issue would simply be that the files were interrupted in being transferred from your computer to the microUSB, causing the files to be "incomplete" which will prevent them from being played since they are theoretically "corrupted".

Comment: He specifically mentions the computer also doesn't play some files anymore, making corruption likelier. And you mean deduce or theorize, instead of "imply".

Comment: First off, I'm a "she." LOL :)

Second, no, I guess I didn't explain this correctly. I have mp4 files on my laptop, where they play just fine. I have 10 of them. All 10 play fine on the laptop. When I transfer them over to the card, only some of them play -- both while the card is in the laptop and while it's in the tablet. 

File size is less than 4GB on all of them. In fact, the ones that won't work on the card are less than 1GB. 

I thought about the "interruption" issue, but I've transferred several times and watch the status bar go to complete, same as the ones that work. 

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

"They do not play"... how do they not play? are you getting an error message? does your media player stop responding? If you are getting an error message what is it?

My GUESS, lacking any other data, is that your media player device appears to crash, when it in fact is just not responding for a very long time (too long for you to wait) because microUSB drive you are using is extremely slow

Not all mp4 files are encoded at the same bitrate, if the bitrate is 1.2 MB per second and your drive can only output 1.0 MB per second then it can't play the file

edit:
The comments on this answer had a back and forth that isolated the problem. Copying files to the SD drive caused random file corruption.
This indicates faulty hardware and a need to replace the SD drive

Comment: It may well be an encoding issue. The ones that it CAN play are encoded at 4MB/sec; not sure how the ones it can't play are encoded. Gonna run it through HandBrake and re-encode, see whether that makes a difference. Thanx for the suggestion. And by the way, I get an error message that says the file cannot be played, both when the card was in the laptop and when it was in the tablet. I'll see what re-encoding does. Thanx again!

Comment: well, there goes that theory. I have them all encoded at 4MB/sec; some work, some don't. This is the error I get: _Can’t play. Try playing something else. This item’s file format may be unsupported, the file extension may be incorrect, or the file may be corrupted. 0xc00d36c4_ ... Thoughts?

Comment: I also tried playing it in Windows Media Player just now (had been trying in the movie & tv app that is in Windows 10); I got this message: _Windows Media Player cannot play the file. The Player might not support the file type or might not support the codec that was used to compress the file._ Tried it in the tablet, too, and no dice. Just says can't play the file. I'm guessing it's somehow getting corrupted when transferred between my laptop and the card, but I have no idea how or why. Thoughts?

Comment: The error is informative and quite useful. What happens if you take a file that gives you that error and copy it back from the usb drive to the HDD? That is, you have the file "my trip 21.mp4" on the PC and it works, you copy it to USB and it doesn't work, not copy it back from the USB to another directory on the PC And try it again. I am thinking maybe the file got corrupted on copy

Comment: Nope, when I transferred it from the microSD back to the HDD, I got the same message. So it would appear SOME of the files are being corrupted upon transfer to the microSD, but not all (some do work on the card). So... that begs the question: How do I transfer the files safely?

Comment: What do you mean "nope"? You just confirmed my suspections are right on the money here, we just have confirmation that some of your files got corrupted. Yes, it was not 100% of the files, but the fact that multiple files get corrupted with each transfer cinches it, this is absolutely a case of file corruption. You do not need to do anything special to avoid this level of file corruption, it simply should not happen. You either have a defective USB slot, or a defective USB stick. one of them needs to go in the trash. It is most likely the USB stick, test a different one

Comment: The "nope" answered your question about copying it back from the USB to the PC. As in, nope, it doesn't work. I am copying the files using a drag/drop via Windows Explorer onto the SD drive (micro is in a regular SD adapter, which is directly in the SD slot on my laptop). I did try the drag/drop onto a regular USB stick, and the files seemed fine. Beginning to think my card may have issues. :( Do you think it would make a difference if I put the microSD into the tablet and transfer via USB cable? I guess it's worth a shot, no?

Comment: Regardless, the problem has been identified and a solution found. Your problem: file corruption when using the USB stick in question. Solution: Throw it in the trash and get a different USB stick. Your assertion that this has anything to do with mp4 or anything else is simply wrong. From your own tests we have now confirmed that it is file corruption

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, but the solution was... ungratifying. It turned out I had bought a dodgy flash drive from eBay with a tampered capacity - what was supposed to be an amazingly large drive was in fact only 8gb, though it showed the faked size in Windows and on a sector scan.

This set me straight: http://www.ebay.com/gds/All-About-Fake-Flash-Drives-2013-/10000000177553258/g.html

What tipped me off was when I copied across about 20gb worth of .mkv files. I found that some of them were working fine, and then everything after a certain point was broken. They were broken even though the file sizes appeared correct, and there were no error messages during the copy.

I tried all sorts of things to fix them - scans, chkdsk etc., but came up with nothing. Sometimes after disconnecting and/or restarting it would accept an extra 1gb video, and it would play while it was still plugged in, but then when I ejected it and plugged it back in that file would be corrupted, as if all of the metadata was gone.

I finally figured out that it was the first 8gb that worked, and everything beyond that was faked. I feel like a total idiot for wasting so many hours, when in the end the answer was obvious - it seemed way too good to be true when I bought it, and it was.

It's one possible reason some of your files will work, but others won't, when there appears to be no rhyme or reason as to why. Hopefully this will save you (or someone else) from wasting time trying to figure out why the universe seems so random and cruel. ;)